# What's the name of this construct - "We went to SuperFunTime, but it really wasn't"?

Tags: clauses

Where the missing clause is assumed to be a [a super fun time].

Or "Unfortunately, the elastic wasn't". Here it would be wasn't [elastic].

I did try to search, but if this has already been asked it's not easy (for me) to search for.

Comment: The name of this construct?  "Humor".

Comment: I mean, you're not wrong. But I'm unable to use that to find other examples or learn more about how to construct or interpret such.

Comment: The blanket term for stopping in the middle of a sentence is 'aposiopesis', but this would seem to merit a hyponym.

Comment: It's what's known in the trade as an "anaphoric island", like _Bill is an orphan, and he misses them_. Anaphoric islands are explained at the end of [this Language Log post](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005043.html).

Comment: That looks like exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much for pointing me to that post. If you post this as an answer I'll consider it correct and mark it as accepted.

Comment: It's a kind of "use/mention pun", much the same as *His get-up-and-go has got up and gone.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Except that it's a sort of "use/no mention pun". (Or is it "no use/mention"?)

Comment: (Or maybe a "useless pun"?)

Answer (score 1):

**Ellipsis**

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ellipsis

> noun [plural =] ellipses
>
> 1. The omission from speech or writing of a word or words that are superfluous or able to be understood from contextual clues.
>    ‘it is very rare for an ellipsis to occur without a linguistic antecedent’